# Gzuncompress Warning in Some Browsers... What to Do?

Tags: php, caching, gzip

My site caches each page daily and for some reason, some browsers (Opera and sometimes Chrome) display a warning message:

```
Warning: gzuncompress() [function.gzuncompress]: data error in /.../router.php on line 42
```

For the most part, it seems like 95% of my traffic is unaffected (or so I believe). Does anybody know of something that needs to be enabled, updated, fixed or tweaked?

Here is the code that the error message refers to:

```
if ( !empty($cache) && ($cache['mod_date'] * 60 * 60 * 24) > $loadTime ) {

$HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"];
if( headers_sent() )
    $encoding = false;
else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, 'x-gzip') !== false )
    $encoding = 'x-gzip';
else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING,'gzip') !== false )
    $encoding = 'gzip';
else
    $encoding = false;

$compressed = $cache['contents'];

header('Content-Type: text/html');
if ( $encoding ) {
    header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
    echo $compressed;
}
else {
    echo gzuncompress($compressed);
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I guess it does not have to do with the browser as much.... The site loaded fine in Opera on another computer and then I updated both computers with the latest version... one showed fine, one displayed error.  Must not have to do with browser / browser versions?!?!

Comment: Line 42 is: echo gzuncompress($compressed);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP manual about [`gzuncompress()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) says: *The function will return an error if the uncompressed data is more than 32768 times the length of the compressed input data…*

You could also try to let PHP do the work for you using [`ob_gzhandler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you... I will give that a try and let you know how it works out.